# Function worked just fine, but now I'm getting Function returned undefined, expected Promise or Value error

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This function worked just fine a few days ago. I did some testing setting the time to `every two minutes` and everything works just as expected. Then when I saw it was all good, I've changed the time to be once a week (`0 0 * * 7`) and actually started working with my product. But this Sunday, the function just failed.

I've been getting this error `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or Value` followed by many of these:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I am confused because everything worked just fine before. I've now tried to change the timing again to do some testing and it doesn't work anymore. I had my editor open the whole time so I reverted all the changes to see if I accidentally changed anything but there were literally no changes other than the timing. What could have happened?

This is the function:

```
exports.createRecurringDeals = functions.pubsub.schedule('11 8 28 10 *').timeZone('Asia/Jerusalem').onRun((context) => {
    db.collection('recurring_deals').get().then(querySnapshot => {

        querySnapshot.forEach(bus => {
            const businessListDoc = bus.data();

            if (businessListDoc !== undefined) {

                return db.doc('businesses/' + bus.id).get().then(busDoc => {

                    const business = busDoc.data();

                    if (business !== undefined) {

                        businessListDoc.list.forEach((deal:string) => {
                            return db.doc('deals/' + deal).get().then(snapshot => {
                                const oldDeal = snapshot.data();
                                if (oldDeal !== undefined) {

                                    const promises: any = [];

                                    const startTime = oldDeal.timestamp_start + 604800000;
                                    const endTime = oldDeal.timestamp_end + 604800000;  
                                    const startTimeDst = oldDeal.timestamp_dst_start + 604800000;
                                    const endTimeDst = oldDeal.timestamp_dst_end + 604800000;

                                    const newDealDoc = db.collection('deals').doc();

                                    const newDeal = {
                                        id: newDealDoc.id,
                                        business_ID: business.id,
                                        business_name: business.name,
                                        business_address_text: business.address_text,
                                        business_address_lat: business.address_lat,
                                        business_address_long: business.address_long,
                                        business_phone_number: business.phone_number,
                                        business_image: business.business_photos[0],
                                        business_categories: business.categories,
                                        business_sub_categories: business.sub_categories,
                                        discount: oldDeal.discount,
                                        sitting: oldDeal.sitting,
                                        items: oldDeal.items,
                                        special:oldDeal.special,
                                        timestamp_start: startTime,
                                        timestamp_end: endTime,
                                        timestamp_dst_start: startTimeDst,
                                        timestamp_dst_end: endTimeDst,
                                        gmt: oldDeal.gmt,
                                        amount: oldDeal.amount,
                                        claimers: [],
                                        active: true
                                    };

                                    promises.push(newDealDoc.set(newDeal));

                                    promises.push(db.doc('recurring_deals/' + business.id).update({ list: FieldValue.arrayRemove(oldDeal.id) }));

                                    promises.push(db.doc('recurring_deals/' + business.id).update({ list: FieldValue.arrayUnion(newDeal.id) }));

                                    return Promise.all(promises).catch(err => console.log(err));

                                } else {
                                    return null;
                                };
                            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                        });
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    };
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            } else {
                return null;
            };
        });
        return null;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: That's a serious indentation issue. You might consider using `async` and `await` in combination with early returns when the condition doesn't apply to make the code more comprehensible

Comment: The error message is correct - you're not returning a promise from the **top level** of your function callback that resolves only after **all** the async work is complete in your code.  It's going to take a lot of rewriting to make this happen.

Comment: I'll try to figure out a better indentation, though I've been changing it so many times I'm not quite sure how to approch this. Do you think it's the indentation that's causing this error though? Because like I've said it executed just fine before.

Comment: @DougStevenson would solving that also solve that other message I've been getting? The one about the credentials? It didn't appear before either. Are they linked somehow or would that be a different issue? I've seen solutions to this message but it's not something I had to do before when everything was working.

Comment: I don't know about that other error.

Comment: @Tsabary Were you able to resolve the issue with the default credentials after all?

Comment: to solve the credentials error you could try adding a file credentials.json where you can store the credentials to the storage you are using and to connect use the credentials from there explicitly. And have you been able to solve the other issue?